# Magento2.3.0 In which file attribute sort order set for layer navigation left side on product list page?

Tags: product-attribute, layered-navigation, magento2.3.0, sort-by-position

I am using Magneto2.3.0 in which the file attribute `sort order set` for  `layered navigation`, left side on `product list page`/`category page` ? 
If any one idea how it is working in Magento default please share it. and please define path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Create `catalog_category_view` file under

> vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list2" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list2.phtml">

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers2" as="details.renderers">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar2" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                <!--
                    <action method="setDefaultListPerPage">
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">2</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">6</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">8</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">all</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">All</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">6</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">9</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">all</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">All</argument>
                </action>
                -->
            </block>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                <!--<argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>-->
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

</body>
```

2. Create `list2.phtml` file under

> **vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/templates/product**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<!--<div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>-->
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
<?php echo $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
<?php
if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
    $viewMode = 'grid';
    $image = 'category_page_grid';
    $showDescription = false;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
} else {
    $viewMode = 'list';
    $image = 'category_page_list';
    $showDescription = true;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
}
/**
 * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
 */
$pos = $block->getPositioned();
?>
<!-- <div class="products wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?> products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?>">
<?php $iterator = 1; ?>
    <ol class="products list items product-items">
<?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
    <?php
    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
    if ($pos != null) {
        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
    }
    ?>
    <?php // Product Image ?>
                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
    <?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
    <?php
    $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
    ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
    <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
    <?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>

                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                <div class="actions-primary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                            <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                <button type="submit"
                                                        title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                                        class="action tocart primary">
                                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if ($_product->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                    <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
        <?php else: ?>
                                                    <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow()): ?>
                                            <a href="#"
                                               class="action towishlist"
                                               title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                               aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                               data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_product); ?>'
                                               data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                               role="button">
                                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                            </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
    $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare');
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    <?php if ($showDescription): ?>
                                    <div class="product description product-item-description">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                           class="action more"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Learn More') ?></a>
                                    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
</div>-->?>
                                    <a href="#"
                                       class="action tocompare"
                                       title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                       aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                       data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>'
                                       role="button">
                                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    <?php if ($showDescription): ?>
                                    <div class="product description product-item-description">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                           class="action more"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Learn More') ?></a>
                                    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
</div>-->
```

> Note : Here, i moved toolbar to sidebar(layered navigation).

I hope it works!

Comment: thanks for reply but i need to left side layer navigation  inside attribute like size price color position set in admin side in product attribute but i need to specific category wise display on listing page order change price size color so how to achieve this

Comment: There is one more way, in admin under sales->product -> your attribute( i.e. color, price, size) there is option sort order, add sorting value there

Comment: I want to show attibute 

1. Size

2. Color

3. Price

from

1. Color

2. Price

3. Size

for specific category only. And other categories show as default

Comment: For particular category, sorry I have no idea.. :(

Comment: OK you know where is set position  for layer navigation and if you know please code file path sent me. thanks in advance

Comment: While editing product attribute, you can set position:
https://prnt.sc/pdd227

Comment: I know that but in coding where  is set position like mangeto define function  something so i need exact location file path